# Matching and replacing variables in columns using AWK

Tags: for-loop, awk

I am matching  and replacing values in `file2.txt` using values in `file1.txt`. The values that don't match need to be replaced by `NA`. I have tried to write a small AWK code below, but doesn't give output as required. Any suggestion or help is welcomed.

```
awk 'FNR==NR 
{ a[$1]=$2;next}
{
for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
$i = ($i in a) ? a[$i] : "NA"
}
}1' file1.txt file2.txt
```

Instead I get output as below:

```
NAk
NAt1
NAp1
...
```

Sample files:
file1.txt

```
EN01    Car
EN28    Bus
EN37    Scooter
EN49    Van
```

file2.txt

```
EN01    EN28
EN28    EN37
ENXX    EN49
EN01    EN28
```

output (I require)

```
Car   Bus
Bus   Scooter
NA    Van
Car   Bus
```

_

Comment: With your example input data and your `awk` program the output is not what you show. Please edit your question and show exactly what you obtain with your inputs.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps

```sh
awk '
    NR == FNR {vehicle[$1] = $2; next}
    function get(id) { return id in vehicle ? vehicle[id] : "NA" }
    {print get($1), get($2)}
' file1.txt file2.txt | column -t
```

The error in your code is the newline after `FNR==NR`: the condition must be on the same line as the action block.
See [the `awk` tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/awk/info).